# Fix RenderConstraintsTransformBox overflowed warning

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a widget that exceeds the size of the display and I would like to show different parts depending on user input.

When using this code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ...
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
            Transform.translate(
                offset: const Offset(-50, 0),  // offset hardcoded to -50
                child: Container(
                  width: 2000,
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
            ...
```

The widget respects the constraints, so the container is fitted to the display. After the transform, you see the background instead of a continuation of the widget.

[image]

I could wrap the widget in an UnconstrainedBox:

```
UnconstrainedBox(
    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
    child: Transform.translate(...)
)
```

This fixes the problem, but results in an error:

> A RenderConstraintsTransformBox overflowed by 1500 pixels on the
> right.

[image: container that's drawn entirely]

I want it to overflow, I don't think this is an error! Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Note: I could use a `SingleChildScrollView` with `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` and use the controller to set position, but to me, this feels like overkill. Hope there is a simpler method. Thanks for the read :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UnconstrainedBox` is not the widget to use for getting rid of inner child overflow warnings. It's used to loosen the constraints.

You can use an `OverflowBox` in this case. Usage example:

```
SizedBox(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  child: OverflowBox(
    minWidth: 150,
    minHeight: 150,
    maxWidth: 150,
    maxHeight: 150,
    child: FlutterLogo(),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I experimented with OverflowBox as well, but wrapping it in SizedBox seems to be mandatory for the OverflowBox to work (at least within a Column/Row) or ... 
Instead of SizedBox, LimitedBox() actually seems to be even nicer with a Row()/Column() parent